# Why is global scope $_GET not seen?

Tags: php, get, global-variables

One of my pages (video.php) is opened using form action as follows:

```
<?php 
//Lots of code, including a WHILE loop

echo "<form action=\"video.php?id=".$row['id']."\" method=\"post\" target=\"_top\">    
<input type=\"image\" src=\"".$image."\" style=\"width:180px;height:120px\"    
alt=\"Submit\"></form>";

?>
```

On the page video.php?id, I get the id as follows and declare other global scope vars. However, why is the $_GET variable not seen in my echoed alert when I submit a form as in the following simplified code?

```
//video.php?id page

<?php session_start();
include 'connect.php';

$Vid = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$login_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION['login_id']);

if (isset($_POST['sample'])) {

    echo "<script>
    alert('$Vid');
    </script>";

}

else//etc.

?>

<html><head></head><body>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" id="Form">
<button name="button" type="submit">Click</button>
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="sample">
</form>

</body></html>
```

When I alert $Vid, nothing is alerted (blank alert box). Obviously, I see the SESSION variable when I alert $login_id. Am I missing something with the $_GET? Is there any way for the global var $Vid to be recognized? If I could use $Vid it would save me 5 or 6 queries based on how my code is currently written.

Comment: The form action has $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], print_r($_SERVER) to see what the exact request is, but I think it will be missing the id=x part.

Comment: This was it...I changed my action to "" instead of  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']....GET vars were now recognized.

Answer (score 1):

This how you can correct

- Put $row['id'] inside a hidden text box with name as "id"
- Your form method is POST, so use $_POST to grab the data in the POST file.

Comment: Thanks...I am already doing this. But it costs me about 5 or 6 queries on my video.php page...I would like to use $Vid directly

Comment: I would suggest then to see the answer from @nietonfir

Answer (score 0):

I think you escaped wrongly and thus the id is not appended (notice the backslash after `$row['id']`?), try the following:

```
echo '<form action="video.php?id='.$row['id'] . '" method="get" target="_top">    
<input type="image" src="' . $image . '" style="width:180px;height:120px"    
alt="Submit"></form>";
```

Imho your coding style is very unreadable with all those backslashes. It's okay to mix single/double quotes where needed…

[edit] and you obviously need to change the method to "get". ;-)

Comment: Looks like a winner, except not `get`.  They are using `post` vars and just submitting to a page that has a `get` query string.

Comment: OK...I'll try it with method=GET...sorry about the slashes...this is how I was trained by someone!!! My bad....the escaping was wrong here....in my actual file's code it was ok though :)

Comment: Changing the method to get gives me a blank video.php page with no id appended...seems like for my page the method needs to be post

Answer (score 0):

Changed  action from $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] to action="" and now the GET variables are seen.

Comment: ah, well, u didn't post the form causing the error then in the beginning of your question…